# Apply and save image effects on Canvas javascript

Tags: css, image, canvas, css-filters

I have to implement image filter with effects like greyscale , blur etc.
I have the image in dataURL format. Can someone guide me on the process to achieve it without losing the image size ?

If I add the image to a canvas for manipulation , it scales to the canvas box size. Also unable to apply css filters on canvas /image and save it . When I save , it has the original image

Answer (score 1):

**Using canvas to apply filters**

**Filter property**

Though chrome and firefox both support the `ctx.filter` property they require the setting of browser flags to activate. Once activated the filter property of the 2d Context uses the CSS filter syntax and applies the filter to all rendering calls. ref [MDN CanvasRenderingContext2D.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter)

```
ctx.filter = "blur(5px)";  // only applies to proceeding rendering calls existing
                           // current pixels remain unchanged
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);  // draw an image blurred 5px
```

To apply a filter to an image. **Only** works on Chrome and FIrefox with the appropriate browser flags set.

```
// assume image is a loaded image
var filteredImage = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = filteredImage.getContext('2d');
filteredImage.width = image.width;
filteredImage.height = image.height;
ctx.filter = "blur(10px) grayscale(100%)";
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0); // draw the image applying the filter
ctx.filter = ""; // turn off the filter as no needed any more

// You can now save the image filteredImage by using
ctx.toDataURL("image/jpeg",0.75);
```

**Simplest solution**

If you need full browser support you will have to find an Javascript filter library, there are many to choose from though I will not endorse any of them.

**Write your own**

The alternative is to write your own filters, (A great learning opportunity) most filters are very simple pixel manipulation functions and there is plenty of information on how the various filters work. To learn more about the 2D API [MDN CanvasRenderingContext2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D) and a quick primer on convolution filters [Image Filters with Canvas](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/)

For example a grayscale filter (the most basic of convolution filters the weighted sum of red, green blue channels is converted to a gray scale)

```
const PERS_R = 0.2;  // approx human perceptual frequency / intensity response for r,g,b popular in the CG world and based on Manhattan 0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722
const PERS_G = 0.7;  // for red green and blue
const PERS_B = 0.1; 
function applyGreyScale(image, percent, perc){ // 0 < percent >= 100
    if(image === null || image === undefined){
        throw new ReferenceError("applyGreyScale argument image is undefined or null");
    }
    const p = percent === undefined ? 1: percent / 100;
    const rp = 1-p; // reciprocal of p
    perc = 1 - (perc === undefined ? 0 : Math.min(1, Math.max(0,perc))); // clamp if defined
    var filteredImage = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = filteredImage.getContext('2d');
    const w = filteredImage.width = image.width;
    const h = filteredImage.height = image.height;
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0); // draw the image
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w ,h); // get the pixel data
    var dat = imageData.data; // reference the pixel data
    var ind = (w * h * 4) - 4; // pixel data array index point to last pixel each pixel is 4 bytes RGBA
    const mean = 1/3; // mean contribution of each channel to gray
    const pr = PERS_R + perc * (mean - PERS_R);
    const pg = PERS_G - perc * (PERS_G- mean);
    const pb = PERS_B + perc * (mean - PERS_B);
    var grey; 
    while(ind >= 0){  // do for all pixels
        grey = dat[ind] * pr;      // get gray by adding each channel's contribution
        grey += dat[ind + 1] * pg; 
        grey += dat[ind + 2] * pb;
        dat[ind] = rp * dat[ind] + p * grey; // mix the grey with the existing colour
        dat[ind + 1] = rp * dat[ind + 1] + p * grey; // mix the grey with the existing colour        
        dat[ind + 2] = rp * dat[ind + 2] + p * grey; // mix the grey with the existing colour
        ind -= 4;
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imageData,0,0); // put the new pixels back on the image
    filteredImage.ctx = ctx; // Add 2D context for later use
    return filteredImage; // return the filtered image
}

/*
To use applyGreyScale(image [, percent [, perc]]) where percent and perc are optional
image is the image to get a gray scale from
percent is the amount of gray to apply 0 is none 100 is full. Default 100
perc is the amount of the perception curve applied to the grey. 0 no perception adjustment, 1 is full perceptual adjustment. Default is 1
Returns image with ctx property added for access to 2D interface
*/
```

And relatively easy to use

```
// convert image to greyscaled image
var dataURL = applyGreyScale(image).ctx.toDataURL("image/jpeg",0.75);
```

Comment: `ctx.filter` works on all browsers, except MS family (Edge and IE).

Answer (score -1):

Add the image to the source of another image:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('id');
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    //The 4th, and 5th parameters set the image at it's own dimensions.
    //The 2nd, and 3rd parameters set the image at the upper left of the canvas.
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    //Your image manipulation code here.
};
img.src = dataurlString;
```

This will make the canvas as big as the image, but I'm assuming you wish to preserve the resolution.

You will also need to put all of your manipulations in the onload listener.

Comment: Hello , Thanks for the response . I am trying the manipulation using filters imageData.style["filter"] = "grayValue(0.5)" / ctx.style["filte"]="grayValue(0.5)" , but the code dont seem to work . Any inputs on the same?

Comment: You can't use `filter` on style. You have to use it directly `ctx.filter`. See @Blindman67's answer.